# Why is my regex to match words in PHP not working as expected?

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP 7.4 as well as PHP 8.2 and I have a regex that I use in PHP to match words (names). To be completely honest, I barely recognize this regex monster I created. Thus this question is asking for assistance in figuring it out. It is basically this:

```
$is_word = preg_match('/^(?![aeiou]{3,})(?:\D(?![^aeiou]{4,}[aeiou]*)(?![aeiou]{4,})){3,}$/i', $name);
```

I’ve been using it for about 6+ years to match names in a script I have created: It will basically return a boolean of `TRUE` or `FALSE` if it matches a word pattern.

But today it returned `FALSE` on two names which should be deemed valid:

- Li
- Drantch

To test this out, you can use the following batch of test names; using pseudo names for example sake:

- Nartinez
- Drantch
- Dratch
- Xtmnprwq
- Yelendez
- Boldberg
- Yelenovich
- Allash
- Mohamed
- Li

I attempted to adjust the regex to set the second `{x,x}` to `{5,}`

```
$is_word = preg_match('/^(?![aeiou]{3,})(?:\D(?![^aeiou]{5,}[aeiou]*)(?![aeiou]{4,})){3,}$/i', $name);
```

It helped in cases which match names like “Drantch” but then it still completely missed two-letter names like “Li.”

How can this regex be tweaked to properly match all names? If not all names, how can it be adjusted to properly match “Drantch” and other obvious names other that “Li.”

Note that, “Xtmnprwq” is a fake test name so I can test negatives as well as positives.

Comment: *btw* `Louie` and `Euanthe` might not be happy with that kind of restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp has the following constraints on words:

- `^(?![aeiou]{3,})` - Can't begin with 3 or more consecutive vowels
- `(?![^aeiou]{4,}` - Can't have 4 or more consecutive consonants in the middle
- `(?![aeiou]{4,})` - Can't have 4 or more consecutive vowels in the middle
- `{3,}` - Must be at least 3 characters long

So then, your problematic examples are as follows:

- `Li` violates the 3 characters requirement.
- `Drantch` violates the 4 consecutive consonants restriction.

Tweak or remove these bits of the regexp to changes the restrictions to allow these names.

Comment: [5 consecutive consonants](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/five-consecutive-consonants)

Answer (score 1):

The `{3,}` in your non-capturing group mandates a minimum string length of 3 characters.  If you want to allow `Li`, reduce it to `{2,}`.

The negated characters class inside your negated lookahead (`(?![^aeiou]{4,}`) has a minimum qualification of 4 consonants, so `ntch` satisfies that and disqualifies the input string.  If you want to allow `Drantch`, increase it to `(?![^aeiou]{5,}`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ivmRR))

```
$array = [
    'Nartinez',
    'Drantch',
    'Dratch',
    'Xtmnprwq',
    'Yelendez',
    'Boldberg',
    'Yelenovich',
    'Allash',
    'Mohamed',
    'Li',
];

// This is the same regex as in the asked question with 3 changed to 2 and
// 4 changed to 5; then I simply used spacing and x to make it more readable.
$regex = <<<REGEX
/
^
(?![aeiou]{3,})
(?:
   \D(?![^aeiou]{5,}[aeiou]*)
   (?![aeiou]{4,})
){2,}
$
/ix
REGEX;

var_export(preg_grep($regex, $array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Nartinez',
  1 => 'Drantch',
  2 => 'Dratch',
  4 => 'Yelendez',
  5 => 'Boldberg',
  6 => 'Yelenovich',
  7 => 'Allash',
  8 => 'Mohamed',
  9 => 'Li',
)
```

---

As for improving your pattern's readability, it would be better to express your exact intention, then generate a set of negated lookaheads before the "core" requirement that all characters must be letters and have a minimum character length.

```
$regex = <<<REGEX
/
^
(?![aeiou]{3})    #doesn't start with 3 consecutive vowels
(?!.*[aeiou]{4})  #doesn't contain 4 consecutive vowels
(?!.*[^aeiou]{5}) #doesn't contain 5 consecutive consonants
[a-z]{2,}         #contains only letters, minimum of 2 characters
$
/ix
REGEX;
```